# How to do Nested For Loops in Functional Style

Tags: javascript, for-loop, functional-programming, nested, higher-order-functions

I'm in the process of learning functional programming, and completely getting rid of `for` loops has been a challenge sometimes, because they provide so much control and freedom. Below is an example of checking if a string is an `isogram` or not (no letters should be repeated). With nested `for` loops, it became an easy solution. Is there a way to do this the functional way with any high order functions or anything else? Any suggestion would be a huge help.

Code:

```
function isIsogram(string) {
  let array = string.split('');
  let condition = true;
  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) { //first loop picks character
    for (j = i + 1; j < string.length; j++) { //second loop compares it rest
      if (array[i].toLowerCase() == array[j].toLowerCase())
        condition = false; //if repeat, the condition false
    }
    return condition;
  }
}
```

Comment: You are `return`ing after the first iteration itself.

Comment: Why not lowercase the whole string first and then split it instead of double lowercasing in every nested iteration? You are not declaring `j` variaable nowhere, is it global?

Comment: Why are you even splitting the string? You can get length of the string and iterate over it. The condition variable is superfluous, you can simply `return false;` instead of the `condition = false;` and put `return true;` at the end of the function. The `return condition;` part should be removed.

Comment: Yes there are two typos here. variable j is declared, not global, and return condition is after both the loops. I split the string into array because initially i was trying to solve this using map/filter/reduce. Gave up, went back to for loops lol. And yes you are completely right, I get rid of condition all together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) or [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) together with a suitable string function:

```
function isIsogram(string) {
    string = string.toLowerCase(); // case insensitive
    return string.split('').every(function(character, index) {
        return !string.includes(character, index+1);
    });
}
```

Instead of [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) you might also have utilised [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

Comment: Thanks a lot Bergi! I had no idea about the includes function, therefore in my mind I was thinking that using two for loops here is a must. This solves the problem very elegantly.

Comment: `return string.indexOf(character, index+1) == -1` does the same, and you probably did know that :-)

Comment: haha no i didnt. Tried it with indexOf and works like a charm. Very interesting indeed.

Answer (score 2):

You can sort the `String` first and then apply `every` on it. It will stop the iteration as soon as two successive letters are the same:

Here is an improved implementation. Credit goes to @Xotic750:

```js
function isIsogram(x) {
  return Array.from(x.toLowerCase()).sort().every((y, i, xs) => i === 0 
   ? true
   : y !== xs[i - 1]);
}

console.log( isIsogram("consumptively") );
console.log( isIsogram("javascript") );
```

The implementation uses `Array.prototype.every`'s second parameter, which represents the index of the current element (of the iteration). Please note that `isIsogram` solely depends on functions and their arguments.

Comment: Nice, but I find that very difficult to digest. `return Array.from(x.toLowerCase()).sort().every((y, i, xs) => i === 0 || y !== xs[i - 1]);` seems clearer to me and is identical I believe?

Answer (score 0):

Another example, like @Bergi but using some ES6 features for comparison.

```js
function isIsogram(string) {
  string = string.toLowerCase(); // case insensitive
  for (let character of Array.from(string).entries()) {
    if (string.includes(character[1], character[0] + 1)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(isIsogram('abc'));
console.log(isIsogram('abca'));
```

How your ES3 style code could have looked (noting some of the issues pointed out in the comments)

```js
function isIsogram(string) {
  string = string.toLowerCase(); // case insensitive
  var length = string.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i += 1) {
    for (var j = i + 1; j < length; j += 1) {
      if (string.charAt(i) === string.charAt(j)) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(isIsogram('abc'));
console.log(isIsogram('abca'));
```