# How can I swap this JavaScript nested For Loop for something more clear and concise?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, functional-programming

I'm new to `JavaScript` and find the following `nested for loop` fugly:

```
    $scope.parents = []; 
      for (var k = 0; k < $scope.children.length; k++) {
         for (var i = 0; i < $scope.todos.length; i++) {
           if($scope.todos[i].todosern == $scope.children[k].todosernm){
              $scope.parents.push($scope.todos[i]);
            }
         }
      }
```

Can anybody tell me how to harness JavaScript's Functional powers and rewrite this in a clear, concise way, without `for loops`, if possible.

While my question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39434953/how-to-do-nested-for-loops-in-functional-style), I believe they are different enough to warrant my asking it.

Please include only constructs that are supported in all modern browsers, ruling out for example, `includes` since that is [not supported by IE or Android](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#compat-desktop)

**EDIT**:

At Nina's sensible request, here is my data model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var TodoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
todosern: String,
todotype: String,
todosernm: String,
salmserna: String,
salmsernb: String,
todotask: String,
todostart: String,
todostartt: String,
todoend: String,
todoendt: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Todo', TodoSchema);`
```

Comment: please add some data as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use this method :

```
$scope.parents = $scope.todos.filter(function(e) {
  return $scope.children.some(function(i) {
    return e.todosern === i.todosernm;
  });
});
```

Just to add for those who can use new features, arrow function make it cleaner:

```
$scope.parents = $scope.todos.filter(e => $scope.children.some(i => e.todosern === i.todosernm))
```

Here is a test with sample data :

```js
var $scope = {
    parents: [],
    children: [
        {todosernm: 'data1'},
        {todosernm: 'data2'},
        {todosernm: 'data3'},
    ],
    todos: [
        {todosern: 'data1'},
        {todosern: 'data4'},
        {todosern: 'data3'},
    ]
}

$scope.parents = $scope.todos.filter(function(e) {
  return $scope.children.some(function(i) {
    return e.todosern === i.todosernm;
  });
});

console.log($scope.parents);
```

Comment: `$scope.children.filter` will produce a list containing items from the `$scope.children` array, judging from his original code what he wants to produce is a list of items from the `$scope.todos` array ("`$scope.parents.push($scope.todos[i])`")

Answer (score 3):

You could use an object as hash table and collect first all children with the given property `todosernm` and later filter only the ones who are in the hash table.

```
var hash = Object.create(null);

$scope.children.forEach(function (a) {
    hash[a.todosernm] = true;
});

$scope.parents = $scope.todos.filter(function (a) {
    return hash[a.todosern];
});
```

For more functional programming, you could replace the first [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) with a [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```
var hash = $scope.children.reduce(function (r, a) {
    r[a.todosernm] = true;
    return r;
}, Object.create(null));

$scope.parents = $scope.todos.filter(function (a) {
    return hash[a.todosern];
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that soon since I have to be away from my computer for an hour

Comment: Thanks for the answer - it works but I find Coldiary's solution a little simpler.  But thank you - I learnt something.

Comment: it may look simpler, but it need for every check a new iteration.

Comment: ok so your solution is more efficient.  Thank you for the info.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to push all elements from `$scope.todos` into `$scope.parents`, for which an entry in `$scope.children` exists, where `todosern == todosernm`.

I assume you have ES6, so you can use arrow functions and sets, to get lookups in constant time.

Try this:

```
var childnames = new Set($scope.children.map(c => c.todosernm))
$scope.parents = $scope.todos.filter(t => childnames.has(t.todosern))
```

Comment: This is a very elegant solution fafl but I think IE doesn't support arrow functions?  Am I right?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Good catch! Same problem with `new Set(iterable)`

Answer (score 1):

Fully functional:

```
$scope.parents = $scope.children.reduce(function(builtList, child) {
  return builtList.concat($scope.todos.reduce(function(builtPartialList, todo) {
    if (todo.todosern === child.todosernm) {
      return builtPartialList.concat([todo]);
    }
    return builtPartialList;
  }, []));
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - it works but is a bit longer than some of the other solutions.  But thank you - I learnt something.

Comment: @DaveChambers Just to point out, it replicates your original functionality exactly while being 100% Functional, which none of the other suggested solutions are. The accepted answer is also 100% Functional but it produces a slightly different result than your original code, but depending on your use case that might not matter.

Comment: Ok.  I'd need to take a look at that when I have time but thanks for the information.